# Create instance from class string in Typescript/Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I have been looking into creating classes from strings in Javascript, until I came across this:

```
var instance = new window[classString]();
```

However, this does not seem to work in Typescript, since there is type information missing.

**Details:**

```
interface SomeInterface{
  structuredData: any;
}

class A implements SomeInterface {

}
```

I am storing JSON serialized class information in a database. Let's say I have a model class `A`, that class's properties are serialized as JSON string in the frontend and sent to the database along with the class name that represents this data, i.e. the database contains a `class_type` column that contains the name of the class. In this case that would be the string 'A'. Now, I would like to get that data back into my application and dynamically construct an instance from that data.

If we look at the Javascript instantiation code I found above, I would love to do something like this:

```
let instance = new window['A']();
instance.structuredData = foo;
```

Since those classes contain generic parameters that adhere to a certain interface I would be able to assign the serialized data to those newly instantiated instances.

I'm using Angular2/Webpack and would really appreciate any hints as to how to do this.

When using the code like I mentioned above, I get the following compiler error:

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or
>   construct signature.

If I try to circumvent the strict type checking by using

```
declare var window;
```

I get the following error:

> window['classString'] is not a constructor

Comment: What error do you get with your TypeScript code?

Comment: @MichaelLiu Added error message.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. If I put `let instance = new window['A']();` in a standalone .ts file, it compiles fine.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Probably has something to do with webpack. My guess is that the class is not available in the global/window space ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I've used Angular 2 but not webpack.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Angular2 uses Webpack under the hood.

Comment: Don't do this. Instead, use a factory.

Comment: @torazaburo I have come up with a solution. Quite honestly, factories are one of my least favourite code patterns. I think they introduce a lot of redundancy and hamper the code's dynamics. There is a place for them, but I try to use Reflection whenever I can instead of a factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Angular2 skillfully abstracts the involvement of Webpack, I don't know exactly how modules are loaded and processed in detail. However, my guess (as mentioned in the comments) is that the class is not available in the window/global space, thus I have come up with a solution that might be correct (tried it and works, but not sure if that's the correct way to do this type of thing):

```
// first I require the module that is named in snake case with a .ts
// suffix based on the string that is stored in the database
// so if the stored string is SomeThing, we require the file
// called 'some_thing.ts'. Note: using lodash to generate that string
const dynModule = require('./' + _.snakeCase(classTypeString));

// next, we get the constructor by the class name from that module
// which is exactly the string that we stored in the db
const klass = dynModule[classTypeString];

// now we have the constructor function of the class and can
// instantiate a new class from that
let instance: SomeInterface = new klass();

instance.structuredData = foo;
```

Comment: The error in the question is specific to Typescript and typing problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could put those classes inside the window object by yourself, even if you are inside other classes:

```
(window as any).example = class {}; // replace with you class
// and then later in code....
const classNameStr = 'example';
const init = new window[classNameStr]();
```

If you don't like to write inside the window object, you could store them in a object/dictionary somewhere in you code instead.
Or simply use Eval (though it's not a good practice to use it):

```
eval(`new ${className}()`);
```